# Howto use notifications in control-based Smart Watch app?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I created my first control-based (V2.0) app for the Sony Smart Watch 2. Now I understand that my app is launched in control mode as opposed to notification mode. Still I do need the notification mechanism to work for my control app. More specific, I want to show a notification-text in full-screen or in the application view's status bar and launch my control app when a user taps it.

How can this be done?

Cheers,

Andrej

Comment: The latest blog on [Sony Developers world](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/12/26/using-both-the-control-notification-apis-for-customised-uis-in-your-smartwatch-2-extension-code/) was about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as lfor mentioned please see our latest blog post about this:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/12/26/using-both-the-control-notification-apis-for-customised-uis-in-your-smartwatch-2-extension-code/

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to start my app in notification mode. I need more control.

Comment: Currently starting in Control mode is not possible.  Will let you know if this changes in the future.